# Why can't I comment on answers to my own question?

Tags: support, migration, comments, user-accounts

Several months ago I was using this site to ask people and I got 90% good answers. In the past I could write a comment about their answers, but now I cannot see comment button.

I can just answer myself. For example, I asked a question 3 hours ago and I got an answer, but I want to explain more! How can I do that?

Comment: OK this is to strange now the comment button is appeared! why just here I can put comment?I tried many times and cannot put a comment and this is an example http://superuser.com/questions/324726/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-print-dialog-box-in-xp

Comment: @AAA You obviously lost your account cookie. If you help us and supply the link to the post in question, a moderator can merge your accounts and you will have the ability to comment.

Answer (score 6):

Your [question](https://superuser.com/questions/324726/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-print-dialog-box-in-xp) was migrated from Server Fault. Since you had not registered on Server Fault, the cookie for Server Fault is not valid for Super User.

Register your account at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/users/login?returnurl=/questions), and use the same openID to register at Super User. Once done, you should be able to claim ownership of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the question itself if you want to provide more details, click `edit` under the tags.

You should be able to comment on answers to indicate why they didn't work.

If that's not possible due to a lost account association, flag your post for moderator attention and inform the moderators that you would like to have your accounts associated. They can do that for you if the IP matches the one you made your post with.

Comment: No, we can't. Not at this state.

Comment: @Sathya: Oh, I see, I missed some context. Should've clicked through to the question... :)